# i want to set the <a> href with the textbox value after i click on #gen?

Tags: jquery, textbox, set, anchor

So this is what i have:

a textbox, label as a link with id of #gen, and an anchor.

what ever i set in the texbox, should transfer to the anchor href attribute after i click on #gen label.

im PRETTY sure i just about have this correct. lol it's driving me nuts why it's not working!

html:

```
<input type='text' value='' />
<label id='gen'>Generate</label>
</br></br>
<a href=''>Download</a>
```

JQuery:

```
var textbox=$('input[type="text"]'); //texbox target into a var// 
var address=$(textbox).val(); // var address//getting Vaue of textbox. Use it for address into link. 

$('#gen').click( function(){
  $('a').attr('href', address);
  //$(textbox).val('Download Ready!');
});
```

oh yea, i used  to have a value in the texbox set but i took it off cuz that would transfer to the anchor href.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' value='' name="address" id="address" />
<label id='gen'>Generate</label>
</br></br>
<a href=''>Download</a>​
```

**JS**

```
$('#gen').click(function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    url='http://'+$('#address').val();
    $('a').attr('href', url);
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hNsm5/)

I think you should use an `id` with the `a tag` and can use a `button` instead of `label` [**see this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hNsm5/2/).

Comment: Oh i have another question now. so i add some more things to my page in JQuery. Now the new address doesn't doesn't show, but instead says 'undefined'.

New Jquery added on:
//when clicked, clear text-box.//
$(textbox).click(function(){
   $(this).val('');
});

//when blurred, value is 'Address Here'.//
$(textbox).blur(function(){   
    $(this).val('Address not Here');
});

These are supposed just some nice enhancements for the textbox but i guess im probably doing them wrong?

Comment: Okay I figured out a way that works, but can you explain to me why it doesn't work this way? Jazak Allahu Khair :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question, can you give me any example of your work. I would like to cooperate you if you need any. Just let me know what you are trying to achieve. May Allah bless you.

Answer (score 2):

Move your `var address` into the click handler:

```
$('#gen').click( function(){
    var address=$(textbox).val();
    $('a').attr('href', address);
});​
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EgLre/)

In your example it sets the `address` to empty string because on page load it's empty yet.

Comment: It worked but not the way i wanted. it added to the folder address and not a new address. still thanks.